# rename elastic-search to elasticsearch

Tags: support, retag-request

The tag [elastic-search](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elastic-search) should be renamed to [elasticsearch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch). The software tagged is [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).

The tag is correct on other SE sites (notably SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder. I saw that once and forgot to do anything about it.

[elasticsearch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) now holds all the questions.